# VB read/write 5 gb text files

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I have an application that reads a 5gb text file line by line and converts double quoted strings that are comma delimited to pipe delimited format. 
i.e. "Smith, John","Snow, John" -->  Smith, John|Snow, John

I have provided my code below. My question is: Is there a more efficient way of processing large files?

```
Dim fName As String = "C:\LargeFile.csv"
Dim wrtFile As String = "C:\ProcessedFile.txt"
Dim strRead As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
Dim strWrite As New System.IO.StreamWriter(wrtFile)
Dim line As String = ""

Do While strRead.Peek <> -1
    line = strRead.ReadLine
    Dim pattern As String = "(,)(?=(?:[^""]|""[^""]*"")*$)"
    Dim replacement As String = "|"
    Dim regEx As New Regex(pattern)

    Dim newLine As String = regEx.Replace(line, replacement)
    newLine = newLine.Replace(Chr(34), "")
    strWrite.WriteLine(newLine)

Loop
strWrite.Close()
```

UPDATED CODE

```
Dim fName As String = "C:\LargeFile.csv"
Dim wrtFile As String = "C:\ProcessedFile.txt"
Dim strRead As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
Dim strWrite As New System.IO.StreamWriter(wrtFile)
Dim line As String = ""

Do While strRead.Peek <> -1
   line = strRead.ReadLine
   line = line.Replace(Chr(34) + Chr(44) + Chr(34), "|")
   line = line.Replace(Chr(34), "")

   strWrite.WriteLine(line)

Loop

strWrite.Close()
```

Comment: have you looked into multi threading?

Comment: You could use a StringBuilder as a buffer to hold a few hundred lines of output at a time. Or look into using a [BufferedStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If this is a regular task, you might even try using physically separate disk drives for the input and output. Also, although I would expect the compiler to move the regex creation outside the loop, you might as well do that.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion by @AndrewMorton, to move the Regex creation outside the loop, you can also pre-compile it instead of using the interpreted mode.  i.e. `Dim regEx As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled)`.  See: [Regular Expression performance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2004/11/12/regular-expression-performance-david-gutierrez/)

Comment: If all you need to do is replace `","` with `|` and remove any remaining double-quotes, then `newLine = line.Replace(""",""", "|").Replace("""", "")` will be much faster than using a regex. My testing of my earlier suggestion of a using a StringBuilder was not fruitful, and using a TextFieldParser was disappointing in its lack of speedup.

Comment: Thanks. Removing Regular Expressions and replacing with line.Replace worked nicely.

Comment: Just a note on that regex.  It could probably have been sped up significantly if you declared it *outside* the loop.  As it is written in your loop, a new instance would have been created for every iteration.  Creating and compiling a regex is fairly expensive. They would have been constantly going out of scope also, which would put a lot of pressure on the garbage collector.

Comment: from personal experience with this sort of work, I'd have to agree with some of @AndrewMorton's suggestions, in particular using a buffered stream, or replacing your line with a stringbuilder might help some, as strings are immutable, so you're creating another instance of a string for every line in your 5gb text file right now (needless to say, that's a LOT of stuff for the garbage collector to hit against)

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and attempted to make a speed improvement by accumulating output lines into a StringBuilder. I also moved the regex declaration outside the loop.

When that did not work, I examined the CPU usage and disk I/O with Windows Process Monitor and it turned out that the bottleneck is the CPU (even when using an HDD instead of an SSD).

That led me to try an alternative method for modifying the text: if all you need to do is replace `","` with `|` and remove any remaining double-quotes, then

```
newLine = line.Replace(""",""", "|").Replace("""", "")
```

turns out to be much faster (roughly fourfold in my testing) than using a regex.

(Further improvement might be possible with multi-threading, as @Werdna suggested, as long as more than one processor is available and you can coordinate writing back the modified data in the correct order.)